# Openpyxl's iter_rows very slow, even though read_only=True?

Tags: python, numpy, openpyxl

I try to write a Python-3 function reading numeric data from an xlsx-file into a numpy array. I typically only want to read a specific area from a specific sheet. The areas may be small (a dozen cells) or rather large (5000 x 10,000 is easily possible). I am barely interested in text and not at all in functions, figures, formats. Here's my approach so far (the code I write is only used by myself, so I do not follow some/many conventions and PEPs):

```
def xlsreadOnly(file, rangeName, sheet = 'Sheet1', dataOnly = True, forceNum = False):
    from openpyxl import load_workbook
    from openpyxl.utils.cell import coordinate_from_string, column_index_from_string
    from numpy import empty, nan
    import io

    with open(file, 'rb') as f:
        in_mem_file = io.BytesIO(f.read())

    wb = load_workbook(filename = in_mem_file, read_only = True, data_only = dataOnly)
    ws = wb[sheet]

    # find the indeces of left-upper and right-lower cells
    areal = rangeName
    w = areal.find(":")
    lu = coordinate_from_string(areal[0:w])
    luR = lu[1]
    luC = column_index_from_string(lu[0])
    rl = coordinate_from_string(areal[w+1:])
    rlR = rl[1]
    rlC = column_index_from_string(rl[0])
    # initialize variable raw 
    raw = empty([rlR-luR+1, rlC-luC+1], dtype = 'object')
            
    ctor = 0
    # iterate over the rows from left-upper to right-lower cell
    for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=luR, max_row=rlR, min_col=luC, max_col=rlC, values_only=True):
        raw[ctor, :] = np.array(row)
        ctor += 1
    
    return raw
```

I use an `in_mem_file` as it speeded up the function a bit in an earlier version. The workbook is loaded as `read_only`, the area of interest is available piece-wise as left-upper row (`luR`), right-lower row (`lrR`) and so on. The variable `raw` is initialised beforehand at the proper size, so there is no `append`.

The interesting part seems to be the loop

```
    for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=luR, max_row=rlR, min_col=luC, max_col=rlC, values_only=True):
```

The worksheet I read is of size 2535 x 4763. If I read an area of size 100 x 4763, the function needs about 4.2 seconds (i5-9600, 3.7GHz, 16GB RAM, SSD), which sounds way too long for my taste. If I reduce the area to 100 x 3, it still takes 4.0 seconds (yes, for 300 cells!). It looks as if the number of columns is practically irrelevant. However, the time scales nearly linearly with the number of rows, so increasing the area to 500 x 4763 takes about 22 seconds. Reading the whole file takes accordingly long.

Removing the conversion to a numpy array in `raw[ctor, :] = np.array(row)` barely contributes to the calculation time.

I really think I missed something horribly obvious, but after searching for days, I still do not see it! Desperate and honest thanks in advance for pointing my head at my mistakes.

**Edit**: @Charlie Clark, your comment is 100% true, the code was not very easy to read and there was some of unnecessary code. I made some changes and hope it is better now. I also updated the text where necessary. I forgot to mention that reading the same 100x3 area from a small worksheet is done a a matter of milliseconds. So the problem seems to be in (my understanding of) `iter_rows()` in the for-loop.

Comment: The code really isn't very readable and any timing will involve other unrelated stuff. There is currently a discussion about the work openpyxl does to pad ranges when the XML source is sparse but I cannot see if that is related to what you're seing.

Comment: @CharlieClark Please consider your comment upvoted, I don't have the reputation yet. Typically the xlsx is not sparse, so there should be no connection. Thanks!

Comment: I think the discussion would be easier on the openpyxl mailing list, and certainly easier with a file. For performance discussions I like to use the file from bug494.